# How can you get the Component name in the logic of an attribute directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have an attribute directive that I will be applying to elements in my DOM. I was wondering if it is possible to somehow get the component name that surrounds the attribute directive in the DOM.

For example, given:

```html
<SomeComponent>
    <div myAttributeDirective>
</SomeComponent>
```

I want to get the name `SomeComponent` from within the attribute directive code.

I know I can pass in anything to the directive, but I'm trying to make it as succinct syntax as possible, and was hoping there was a creative way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I did end up figuring out a way to do this, although it might be brittle in regards to future versions of Angular. The trick is to access the component instance from the `ViewContainerRef` within your directive, and then use the power of the component's `constructor()` to get the name.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[yourDirective]'
})
export class yourDirective {
    constructor(private _view: ViewContainerRef) {}
    ngOnInit {
        let component = (<any> this._view)._view.component;
        console.info("Component Name: ", component.constructor.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is not possible from within the component tags. You have to pass in the components name by an attribute defined in the TS-file.

This article is about a similar topic, but even here you have to prepare a variable inside the TS-file that you then pass as an attribute.

[Accessing `selector` from within an Angular 2 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188216/accessing-selector-from-within-an-angular-2-component?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

The typescript file core.d.ts file doesn't export the local _view object and you get an error in your linting or code completion when accessing _view. You can trick that like this:

`const context = this.viewContainerRef['_view'].component.constructor.name;`

But it can change after an update since this is not an exported part of the ViewContainerRef