# Angular: How can I access the property `selector` from the `Component` decorator inside the Component?

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

What I want (pseudocode):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  ....
})
export class SomeComponentComponent { 

    constructor() {
        console.log(@COMPONENT.SELECTOR); // logs 'app-some-component'
    }

    ....
}
```

**Background:**

I have a simple component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-component',
  ....
})
export class SomeComponentComponent { ....
```

Now inside this component, I want to create an unique identifier which should contain some the name of the component.

Example:

```
'app-some-component_' + UuidUtil.generateUUID();
```

obviously it would be nicer if I do this with:

```
SELECTOR + '_' + UuidUtil.generateUUID();
```

but then I have to declare the selector as variable outside and it I get problems because my IDE (Webstorm) teslls me unkown selector in the *.html template.

How can I achieve this.

**@duplication**
The solution posted there is pretty hacky because requires element ref which is cast to lowercase. I hope now, after 2 years, there is a better way. Maybe also due to the further development in typescript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing \`selector\` from within an Angular 2 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188216/accessing-selector-from-within-an-angular-2-component)

Comment: Edit: addressed duplication. But thanks, I had a different title before under which I didn't find it.